# how float all elements to left and clear right of one to show several elements below together?

Tags: css, html, css-float

We have four div that must shown as below:

```
|--------|------|
|Big Area|div 1 |
|        |------|-------|
|        |div 2 | div 3 |
|        |------|-------|
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|--------|
```

I try this:

```
<html><head>
<style>
#big_area {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#div_1 {
    float: left;
    clear: right;
}
#div_2 {
    float: left;
}
#div_3 {
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="big_area">big area</div>
<div id="div_1">div 1</div>
<div id="div_2">div 2</div>
<div id="div_3">div 3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but it doesn't work. when I set `clear:left` to `div 2` my `div 2` and `div 3` move to end of scene below the `Big Area` and it is not true result
do you have any solution?
Thanks anyone and thank you Animuson for wiki. I read your [Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-float/info) and it describe that i can't use `float:right` in my case. then I try to say problem in one other way to you.
see I have so many `div`s (N number of `div`s) with different width and height. I must show this `div`s in a row. for example like below:

```
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-----|
|Div 1|Div 2|Div 3|Div 4|Div 5| ... |Div N-1|Div N|
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------|-----|
```

I `float` all of `div`s to `left` and then all of them show in one row (this row break automatically in related of my windows width). but I need break before some of `div`s certainly. for example I need break after `Div 3`.
Then I try adding `clear:left` to my `div 4`, it is working so good and my `div 4` and any number after that (div 5, ..., N-1, N) show in new line but if my `div 1` has big height (like `Big Area`) I won't my other `div`s go to below of `Big Area` but they go with `clear:left` solution. see below result:

```
|-------|-----|-----|
| Big   |Div 2|Div 3|
| Area  |-----|-----|
|(div 1)|
|       |
|-------|
|-----|-----|-----|-------|-----|
|Div 4|Div 5| ... |Div N-1|Div N|
|-----|-----|-----|-------|-----|
```

cause I try to add `<br />` tag after `div 3` and then `div 4` and any other `div`s after that moved to new line but sadly it shown as below:

```
|-------|-----|-----|
| Big   |Div 2|Div 3|<br />
| Area  |-----|-----|
|(div 1)|Div 4|
|       |-----|
|       |Div 5|
|       |-----|
|       | ... |
|       |-----|
|       | N-1 |
|       |-----|
|       |  N  |
|       |-----|
|       |
|-------|
```

Oh I find The Answer ..!!!!!! :D :) :D/
you can see my answer soon below

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
#big_area {
     display: inline-block;
     float: left;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
    } 

​#div_2, #div_3 {
    display: inline;
   }​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="big_area">big area</div>
<div id="div_1">div 1</div>
<div id="div_2">div 2</div>
<div id="div_3">div 3</div>
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/89Pzh/)

Unless you're trying to do more with it that you're not saying, this should work fine. Clear in this case is unnecessary. Unless you specify the element to be `inline` or `inline-block`, the line is going to break after `div_1` by default.

Comment: You and the OP might want to read through the [css-float tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-float/info) for how clearing works.

Comment: div_2 and div_3 may require styles that can't be applied to inline elements (width, height, vertical padding, etc). Using inline-block instead doesn't work in IE7, if support for IE7 is required.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an option, this would be a far simpler problem to solve if you put divs 1, 2, and 3 in a container. All divs with the possible exception of div 1 could be floated left.

```
<div id="big_area">big area</div>
<div id="small_area">
    <div id="div_1">div 1</div>
    <div id="div_2">div 2</div>
    <div id="div_3">div 3</div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, I think you'll have a very tough time finding a reliable, cross-browser solution. If the divs have fixed heights and widths, you could probably manage something with absolute positioning, but that's not an ideal way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer :D
I was adding `<br />` after `div 3` in my `javascript` code with using of `document.createElement` like below:

```
var temp = document.createElement('br');
document.getElementById('all_of_div_container').appendChild(temp);
```

I change my code to below and it is work so so good:

```
document.getElementById('all_of_div_container').innerHTML += "<br />";
```

this ways add same code to my HTML but I don't know why `appendChild(temp)` show all of `float:left` items in new line (as I say and draw in my question) ...!
anyway `innerHTML` work so well.
thanks
Have fun ;)